# yii2. Выборка с исключением

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать выборку в yii2 таким образом, что бы исключить уже имеющиеся элементы у пользователя?
Этих элементов может быть тысячи. Как оптимально?

У меня сейчас так:

```
$ids =  Product::find()
 ->select('template_id')
 ->andWhere(['user_id' => $user_id])
 ->column();  
$tmp = Template::find()
 ->andWhere(['not', ['id' => $ids]])
 ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать join таблицы Template и выбрать все записи которых нет у этого пользователя.